# how to Open a same url on multiple chrome instances

Tags: google-chrome, url, google-chrome-devtools, multiple-instances

I would like to know how to open same URL on all my chrome instances at the same time with a single click or paste of the URL, is it possible to run create a script for such or any other possibility?

```
{
  "urls": [
    "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
  ]
}
```

> for ex: i have 10 chrome instances, i would like to open (xyz.com)
>   website on all my chrome instances with a single click or paste of
>   URL.

hope I'm clear with the Problem that i would like to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Use Web Driver / Selenium, from any language you like, e.g. Python or Java. Open as many instances as you need and feel free to use the same URL in each instance.

Comment: Thank you @mentallurg , this will help me alot. <3 Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

this helped me out :D

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://google.com/'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)

for i in range(1, 6):
    chrome_path1 = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile '+str(i)+'" %s'
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path1).open(url)
```

Thank you, Maybe i use Web Driver soon to automate stuff. i dont know previously about it. thank you for you time and knowledge.